# can we use option (recompile) with update statment in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @tbl table (id int , name varchar(100))

insert into @tbl(id,name)
value(1,'ravi')

update @tbl 
set name = 'Shyam'
where id = 1
```

Here my question is if we have 1 million records in the table and we want to update all of those, so if we will use option (recompile) with update then will it be optimized query or not. If not then what would be best?.

Comment: `@tbl` is a bad choose in your case... a bit preferable to use `#tbl`

Comment: Are you using a select statement as the source of your values? Perhaps if you could post the actual update statement instead of an example like this it would help us.

Comment: _"we have 1 million records in the table and we want to update all of those"_ - what kind of optimization are you looking for? You need to read and write every single row from that million with no options.

Answer (score 0):

> can we use option (recompile) with update statment in sql server

Yes,You can use Option(Recompile) with Update Statement...

> Here my question is if we have 1 million records in the table and we want to update all of those, so if we will use option (recompile) with update then will it be optimized query or not. If not then what would be best?.

Option(Recompile) does not Optimize statements,It instructs SQL Server to construct   a new plan and dont store it in Cache..

If you are running lot of queries with the same predicates, as shown in question  and if the data had increased a lot ,this results in inaccurate statistics.so Option(Recompile) instructs SQL to use new plan based on current data and also instructs it to not store it in cache...

> What are the other options ?

This query i believe is sample one and as you said you will be having million records..

```
update @tbl 
set name = 'Shyam'
where id = 1
```

The above query efficiency Depends on
1.Number of indexes...More the indexes less the efficiency
2.Locking,blocking on your system
and also many factors like RAM,is the table is memory or whether SQL should read from disk..